# Converting from D3js 2.4.4 to 3.5.5

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The example runs with D3js 2.4.4: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html
I would like to make it run with version 3.5.5

The first error I get is

> TypeError: x is not a function /line 52
>
> .attr("x", x(0))

What should I change?

**Some progress**

It looks lik the first problem was that D3.time came from the seperated D3.time.js that I was still including after replace D3.js with version 3.5.5.
I have now removed html inclusion of d3.time.js and d3.csv.js.
But now I get:

> TypeError: **d3.event.transform is not a function** //Line 110
>
> **d3.event.transform(x);**

Comment: Getting this example running under version 3 is discussed in detail [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/6p7Lbnz-jRQ).

Comment: And as a sanity check [here's the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/b8yO66lazDzIQ0Wf3RRM?p=preview) from that post working.

Comment: Thank you, I had already seen the post but the sanity check helped finding some mising detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/6p7Lbnz-jRQ

Sanity check code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/b8yO66lazDzIQ0Wf3RRM?p=preview

Changes

1. Assign svg.append('svg:rect') to a variable. `var rect = 
   svg.append("svg:rect") ...`
2. Comment/remove line `.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom))`
3. Bind event AFTER domain was defined using line 
   `rect.call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).on("zoom", zoom));`. ! Notice the additional `.x(x)` in this new line.
4. Comment/remove line `d3.event.transform(x);` in `function zoom(){...}`